# Java JPA write object to binary file

Tags: java, jpa, binaryfiles

- Database (User)
  ID     Name
  1         Ali
  2        Abu
  3      Ahmad
- WriteBinaryFile.java

  ```
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UserPU");
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

  Query query1 = em.createNativeQuery("select * from user",User.class);
  List<User> list = query1.getResultList();

  for(User userList: list){
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.dat");
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

      oos.writeObject(userList);
      oos.close();
  }
  ```
- ReadBinaryFile.java

  ```
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.dat");
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

  User user1 = (User) ois.readObject();
  ois.close();
  System.out.println(user1.getID+" "+user1.getName());
  ```
- When I read ReadBinaryFile.java, I only can get the output like the following: 
   3 Ahmad
- My expected output:
  1 Ali
  2 Abu
  3 Ahmad
- What am I doing wrong? How can I solve it?

Comment: The problem obviously seems to be of the data contained in `List<User> list`. Do the proper debug to find the reason why your query returns a single result rather than all the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't you overwriting the file on each loop?

```
for(User user: list){
    //overwrites the file on each loop
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.dat");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(user);
    oos.close();
}
```

You need to either create a new file for each user or write the entire list and read that back in.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.dat");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

oos.writeObject(list);
oos.flush();
oos.close(); 

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.dat");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

List<User> users = (List<User>) ois.readObject();
ois.close();

for(User user : users){
    System.out.println(user.getID() +" " + user.getName());
}
```